# Div inside div (100% height) and keep footer at the bottom - JSFiddle

Tags: html, css, height

I've created the below jsfiddle recreating my problem, I want that the .dashboard & .inner-dashboard have always a 100% height and keep the footer always at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/rv7xN/1/

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <body>
        <div class="dashboard">
            <div class="inner-dashboard">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.dashboard{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: -60px;
  background-color:green;
}
.inner-dashboard{
  height:100%;
  padding-bottom: -60px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audre7/7q4dP/2/)

I had to modify the html to have a common container for the dashboard and the footer.

```
<div id="wrap">

        <div class="dashboard">
            <div class="inner-dashboard">

            </div>
        </div>
    <div id="footer"></div> 
</div>
```

I turn the `wrapper` (common container) in a table and the other elements in table-cell.
So even if your dashboard is height 200%, the footer's still at the bottom.

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
#wrap {
position:absolute;
display:table;
height:100%;
width:95%;
padding-bottom:60px;
}

.dashboard{
  width: 95%;
  height: 200%;
  display:table;
  border:5px solid green;
}
.inner-dashboard{
 width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  display:table-cell;
   border:5px solid red;
 }
#footer {    
    display:table;
    height: 60px;
    width:95%;
    border:5px solid blue;
    bottom:-10px;
}
```

Is that it ?!

Answer (score 0):

I have added modified your css and added `position` attribute

I hope the revision solves your issue: [UPDATE] http://jsfiddle.net/saurabhsharma/rv7xN/3/

Comment: the .inner-dashboard should be 100% height as well. Also with your solution the footer no is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I have updated the revision above, and Footer is at absolute bottom, its appearing somewhat above in jsfiddle, but in actual it'll appear in absolute bottom.
If you find the it valuable please accept the answer.

Comment: if the position of the footer is absolute when the dashboard grown up over 100% then the footer no is at the end of the page.

Comment: @darkcode please try the code on a html file and run it on your local and see.

Comment: In other case make your `#footer bottom: -10px;` it'll work on jsfiddle

Comment: It doesn't work, when the .dashboard have any content and the height is over 100% (for example make .dashboard min-height: 200%) the footer no is at the end of the page.